# How To get excel to Automatically copy from the newest file in a folder instead of picking the file?

Tags: excel, vba

I am currently using the following macro to copy from a sheet in a closed workbook where I use msoFileDialogFilePicker to select the file I want to copy from.  I am wondering if there is a way for the newest file in a folder (C:\testfile) to be automatically selected in the macro instead of having to manually select it everytime.

```
Sub NewCopyTest()

Dim FileName As String

FileName = ""

With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)

.Title = "Select File"

.Filters.Add "Excel File", "*.xls?"

.AllowMultiSelect = False

If .Show Then

    FileName = .SelectedItems(1)

End If

End With

If Len(FileName) < 4 Then Exit Sub 'No file selected

Dim TempWorkbook As Workbook, CurrentSheet As Worksheet

Set CurrentSheet = ActiveSheet 

Set TempWorkbook = Workbooks.Open(FileName, ReadOnly:=True)

CurrentSheet.Range("A1:CF500").FormulaR1C1 = "=" & TempWorkbook.Worksheets("Daily Proj").Range("A1:CF500").Address(True, True, xlR1C1, True)

TempWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=False

Set TempWorkbook = Nothing

Set CurrentSheet = Nothing

 

End Sub
```

Comment: Plenty of previous posts on this topic: https://www.google.com/search?q=vba+select+most+recent+file+site:stackoverflow.com